# How to mock Optional bean in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, springmockito

In my `SpringBootApplication`, I have a `bean` which injects another optional bean (like shown below)

```java
@Service
public class A {

    //B is another @Component from one of the dependencies
    private Optional<B> b;
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am writing an integration test for `class A` where I need to `@MockBean` `Optional<B> b`. However since `Optional` is a final class, spring mockito raises following error

> Cannot mock/spy class java.util.Optional
>   - final class

Is there a way around this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am really curious about why putting `Optional` with a Component. Because Spring always will instantiate the `B` component so the Optional doesn't make sense here, since the idea of Optional is handling the likely `Null` or `Empty` value, and in this scenario it never gonna be empty.

Comment: As far as I understand, it is an alternative to @Autowired(required = false)

Comment: I understand your point of view. Although, as long as we can we should let spring handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Optional.of(b)`.

If you use mockito with annotations, then you can't use `@InjectMocks` because your optional will not be known for mockito. You have to create your service `A` yourself. Something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {
    @Mock
    private B b;

    private A a;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        a = new A(Optional.of(b));
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but I chose not to modify production code to make the test work. Thanks anyway. I chose to use `@Autowired(required = false)` instead

Answer (score 0):

You should actually mock the actual bean using `@MockBean` or `@MockBeans` or `TestConfig` class and Autowire the `Optional` with mocked bean

```
@Autowired
private Optional<B> OptionalB;

@MockBean
private B b;
```

Comment: This should have technically worked however I am not able to get the bean injected. I've fallen back to @Autowired(required = false)

Answer (score 0):

Although [Lino's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5515060/lino) [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60401351/3275390) answer works perfectly, I chose not to modify the production code to make the test work. I've instead modified my code like below:

```java
@Service
public class A {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private B b;
    ...
    ...
}
```