# How to Mock Optional Autowired field

Tags: java, spring, mockito, option-type, autowired

I am trying to make a unit test with Mockito and I cannot find any way to mock my constructor's optional autowired field.

Here is my constructor:

```java
@Autowired
public BatchInputManager(
    BatchInputContentRepository batchInputContentRepository,
    Optional<List<BatchInputExecutor>> batchInputExecutors) {
    // ...
}
```

And here is how I try to mock these fields :

```java
@InjectMocks
BatchInputManager batchInputManager;
@Mock
BatchInputContentRepository batchInputContentRepository;
@Mock
List<BatchInputExecutor> executors;
```

For the record, the `BatchInputExecutor` class is an abstract class and I defined a class that extends it in my test.
When I run my code, the optional that should contains all the extended classes of `BatchInputExecutor` is not empty, it is null; and the repository is not null.
How am I supposed to mock the value of the optional field in my constructor ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd setup the mocks in the `@BeforeEach/@BeforeAll` method of the JUnit test.

```
@BeforeEach
public void mocking(){
    var repoMock = ... mock repo ..
    var executorMock = mock(BatchInputExecutor.class)
    // configure executorMock here 
    var batchInputExecutors = Optional.of(List.of(executorMock))
    var batchInputManager = new BatchInputManager()
    ... set the class level fields here .. 
}
```

Comment: So you're telling me that there is no way of using Mockito's annotations here and I have to setup manually my mocks ?

Comment: You can try like this ... 

@Mock
Optional<List<BatchInputExecutor>> executors;

But then you'll need to configure the mocks somehow anyway

Comment: This can also help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60401256/how-to-mock-optional-bean-in-spring-boot

Comment: We can't mock optional fields because it's throwing an error 'Cannot mock/spy class java.util.Optional'

Comment: Then its only manual

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use Mockito's annotations in this case:

Change this

```
@Mock
List<BatchInputExecutor> executors;
```

To this

```
@Mock
Optional<List<BatchInputExecutor>> executors;
```

And configure mockito to supports final classes and methods. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018295/10744129

Comment: Thanks for this I can now handle Optional in my test with annotations. It leads to two issues now : this code is returning null in my constructor : `executors.orElseGet(ArrayList::new)` and the defined mockExecutor that extends the `BatchInputContentExecutor` is not in the Mocked list